# Deploying rails application on Heroku with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

I have application running locally on rails with postgres. Everything works fine. Im new to rails and i wanted deploy my second application on heroku fallowing this guide:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3
When i created new app, i saw it working, then i pushed my app, and couldnt run heroku run rake db:migrate -app "MY NEW APP NAME", because of many errors. Some of them:

DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins!

rake aborted! An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::Error: ERROR: column "confirmed" of relation "orders" already exists

When i try to launch my app i see: "We're sorry, but something went wrong.".
If there already existing columns it shouldnt run locally i guess. What could went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins!

Since vendor/plugins folder is deprecated in rails 3 and completely removed in rails 4.
So if you have no plugins in vendor/plugins folder then you should remove that folder. If any plugin  http://code.coneybeare.net/how-to-convert-simple-rails-23-style-plugins.

Have you pushed your database already and then run migrations?

Comment: So i deleted this folder (it was empty except 1 git file) and then when i try to push it returns "Everything is up-to-date". And there's still same error.

I pushed every migration and database files and then tried to run migration but without result.

Comment: If you already pushed your database using tabs or any other way then table and "confirmed" column already exists there thats why it throws error during rake migrations

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about losing the data in the database on heroku you could try

```
heroku run rake db:reset --app YOUR_APP-NAME
```

This will drop all tables in your database and re-run all your migrations from the start